# Is there a way to track the time between sequence of pages (e.g. wizard)

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a wizard sequence in my website and I want to know the time used for users to start the wizard and finish it. That way I could know which page can be optimized or something like that.

Can we use Google Analytics for this?

Comment: I do not know Google Analytics hardly at all nor do I know PHP- I use another language and analytics tool, but I suspect that with PHP, assuming that the *wizzard* is written in PHP, or even with JavaScript, there should be an option. But push come to shove, you can always use a single pixel image of two different names and use a log analyzer (maybe) or simply write a quick script to read the log file or manually get a feel by manually looking at the log file.

Answer (score 1):

In Universal Analytics you can create own dimension and metrics. More about: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets

You can push data to analytics on page loading (when user comes to the wizard) and when ends it (by clicking "finish" or something like that). If you send time of entrance and time of exit, difference will be a time on site.

Comment: But can I breakdown the time between sub pages?

Comment: Try to add as many steps as you need and calculate a time between steps

Comment: Can I use the old analytics (the `_gaq`) one for this?

Comment: If you'd like to create custom dimension, you need to use Universal Analytics with analytics.js lib.